# Cannot view or delete google project: permissions required resourcemanager.projects.delete

Tags: google-cloud-platform, permissions

I seem to have lost access to one of my gcp projects and cannot view its settings/resources and cannot delete it or shut it down.

When I try to delete it I get the error "permissions required resourcemanager.projects.delete" and when I try to view the IAM settings I get the error "Missing permissions:  resourcemanager.projects.getIamPolicy"

How would I go about deleting or shutting it down? This especially after what seems to be an attempt to install a time-triggered cloud script on the account.